# Xcode Build and Run vs Build and Debug

Tags: xcode, debugging, build

When working in Xcode (3.6), I've noticed that when you first create a project and most of the time, the icons at the top show "Build and Run" and "Run".

Occasionally, they will switch to "Build and Debug" and "Debug".

Functionally, I haven't noticed any difference, though I'm sure there is some in the way the compiler functions.

My main question is really: How do you reset Xcode so that the icons go back to "Build and Run" again? (I happen to like the nice green icons rather than the yellow debug ones because the debug ones remind me how ignorant I am when it comes to Cocoa...lol)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am using Xcode 3.2.6 and I think the "Build and Run" / "Build and Debug" button is dynamic. It shows the most recent behavior you did.

To switch back to "Build and Run", use menu item "Run" -> "Run - Breakpoints Off" to run the target once. The button should be "Build and Run" again.

Another way to "Build and Run" when the button is shown as "Build and Debug" is to press the `Option` key then click the button. The button will switch to the other status while you hold the `Option` key.